# Eclipse neon cannot create android application project

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm very new to eclipse, and for a first project I want to make an android app. The problem is that every time I try to create the project, I get all these errors about 'Theme.AppCompact.something". I know many people have asked this question, but either I can't get it to work or I don't understand. If you could answer like I'm 5 or use screenshots that would be great (since I have been trying to fix this forever now).

I'm very interested about java and eclipse (coming from C# unity) and I want to start this android project but I cannot with this error.

Comment: Why don't you use Android Studio?

Comment: When you don't have a Java background I suggest to **first** work on that part! And then start looking for tutorials that guide you end to end on building Android apps. Any other approach will cost you much more time (and willpower)! It starts with using the appropriate tools. And for Android that is *not* eclipse.